# simplehtmldomparser - php - not reading display none elements that are shown in firebug

Tags: php, domparser

I am using simplehtmldomparser built on php to read content from a url.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

I am trying to retrive a element with "display:none" which I can see in firebug. But that element is not shown when I retrive the dom in php.

Any reason for this? and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: post the code, how you are retrieving via simple HTML DOM?

Comment: include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('url_of_the_website');
$tags = $html->find('.classname');
for($i=0;$i<count($tags);$i++)
  echo $tags[$i];

Comment: change find to $html->find('.classname',0); and check if you get any output

Comment: //I used the following code also for testing. Here I did not get the text that is there inside elements with "display:none".

$html->load_file($urlofsite);
echo $html->plaintext;

Comment: Hello Lenin,
I tried $html->find('.classname', 0); also. It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to read javascript generated content using simplehtmldomparser as the php script will not execute any of the javascript in the website.

So I used imacros to extract the javascript generated content and then used simplehtmldomparser to read the required content.